# RSA Certificate Owner and Issuer line meanings?

Tags: rsa

Apologies if this question is not in the right place.

I've recently been looking through some RSA certificates ( specifically, Android apk .rsa files) and I'm having trouble deciphering the one and two letter combinations in the Owner/Issuer lines.

ex: CN, OU, O, L, ST, C

L, ST, and C are Location, State and Country, I think, but what are the others?

Comment: Look for X500 and [X.509](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CN is common name, OU is orginizational unit, O = organization.

So we could have CN="John Johnson", OU="Sales", O="Acme Corp." or something like that.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/keytool.html only mentions these, but I've seen Email as well.

Comment: Are there any additional entries(?) that could show up on those lines?